# How to make Nautilus list `..` for parent directory in all folders

Tags: nautilus, preferences

I've scoured the File Manager Preferences, GSettings and The Internet as best I can, and I cannot find the setting the hides the `..` meta folder for parent directory. Even with "Show Hidden Files" turned on.

I am most interested in this item showing up in file-open dialogs which appear to respect the settings that the file manager declares. But would be just as happy for it to be pervasive everywhere when turned on.

It would make the most sense to only show this meta folder in List View, but even there it is absent.

---

This is not asking for a gui button, its asking for a file listing accessible by name such that typing <kbd>.</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd> would select the parent meta-folder and navigate to it.

Comment: You can press Ctrl-L, `..` and Enter.

Comment: @muru that does work in both file open dialog and normal File Manager. I will mark it an acceptable answer if you post it.

Comment: Oh, I assumed you wanted a GUI button. Here's an easier keyboard method: press Alt+Up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a type-able address bar by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>, where you can enter a relative or absolute path (with completion), and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to navigate to that path. If you want to see the breadcrumb, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> again.